# Is a comma required after "Researchers"?

Tags: writing, commas

Sentence:

> Researchers Sprecher and Regan 1996, found that males typically feel more positively about losing their virginity because it removes an undesired stigma.

Do we require a comma after 'Researchers'?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please explain why you think it should have a comma or not?

Comment: It should **not** have a comma because in general we don't put a comma between the subject of a sentence and the verb. Remove the comma and put *1996* in parentheses. *Researchers S and R (1996) found...* Then you have smooth sailing, no longer a comma separating the subject from the verb. One assumes you are using a style guide that uses this type of reference (sources mentioned by surname and a year in the body of the text), with a bibliography that will contain all such references.

Answer (score 2):

So, Sprecher and Regan are the researchers. If you get confused in such context, simply replace the words and it'll have clearer message for you.

Turn 'researchers' into 'singers' and change the names.

> Singers, Justin and Shakira, found that...

If you put a comma after 'singers', it means some singers + Justin + Shakira, isn't it?

So, if you put comma, in fact, you add an ambiguity of separating researchers from those names who are actually researchers. :)

Answer -**No**, you don't put a comma there!

Answer (score 0):

we don't require comma after researchers.if we place comma it reflects the meaning like
"**researchers and Sprecher and Regan**" and may lead to confusion that Sprecher and Regan are not researchers .

Answer (score -1):

The possible choices how to correct your sentence:

> 1. Researchers (Sprecher and Regan 1996) found that males typically
>    feel more positively about losing their virginity because it removes
>    an undesired stigma.
> 2. Researchers, Sprecher and Regan (1996), found that males typically feel more positively about losing their virginity because it removes
>    an undesired stigma.

Comment: It's fine without the comma... It's a title... You wouldn't put a comma if it were doctors: *Doctors Sprecher and Regan found...*